# Selecting nth-child by variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 divs with different classes. In each there's a row of 5 buttons, eache one is the same size.
If i click the button in top row I want the button that is directly under him to hide.

```
$('.top-row .button').click(function(){
    var indexx = $(this).index()+1;
    $(".bottom-row .button:nth-child(indexx)").show().fadeOut(800);
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Any advices?

Comment: It's simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to build the selector string yourself:

```
$(".bottom-row .button:nth-child(" + indexx + ")").show().fadeOut(800);
```

JavaScript won't peek into your string constants looking for variables to interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `indexx` is not evaluated inside the selector string value itself. That said, I don't think you actually need the `:nth-child()` selector specifically; rather, you could just use `.eq()` and pass the index as is:

```
$(".bottom-row .button")
  .eq($(this).index())
  .show()
  .fadeOut(800);
```